# How do you deal with Listview.separated() separators getting rebuilt and changing content of the separators?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `ListView` which is a bunch of news articles.  The news articles have a date associated with them, for example `March 3`, `March 4`, etc..

Now if the articles have the same date I want them to be grouped together, so it would go something like this:

> `March 3`
>
> > News Article 1
> > News Article 2

> `March 4`
>
> > News Article 3

> `March 5`
>
> > News Article 4
> > News Article 5
> > News Article 6

What I've tried to do is to create a variable that tracks the last seen date:

```
final _listofuseddates = [];
```

The date itself is a `String` located here: `data["date"]`

If the date presented by the article data is different, then it will insert a new separator text with the date:

```
         ListView.separated(
                        itemCount: data.length 
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

                          return NewsItem(
                            index: index,
                            data: data[index]
                          );

                        },
                      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

                        final _thisdate = data["date"];

                        if (_listofuseddates.contains(_thedate)) {
                            return Container();
                        }
                        else
                          {
                          _listofuseddates.add(_thedate);
                          return Text(_thedate.toString());
                          }

                      },
                    ),
```

Whats happening here is the date of the current article is being compared to the List of dates we've already seen, if its a novel date, then a Separator text is added with that date, for example `March 3`.  If the date was already seen, then no separator, or at least an empty imperceptible separator is put in `Container();`.

Now this is OK when the list first loads, but as soon as you scroll the list, this all changes and all the dates erase themselves on the fly, because the listview is constantly rebuilding itself and of course the Date was already `seen`.  Worse, yet if you scroll down and then backup the list then things will sometimes reverse themselves, as the first unseen date is the last item as you are scrolling up.

Is there a better approach to this seemingly simple concept of adding date headers to a bunch of list items to keep them "grouped"?

Comment: how about creating listItem on initState?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Data is coming from http request, so would it work in initstate?

Comment: Are you getting  all data at once or using pagination? If all at once; You can create a future method to load data and then call method inside initState

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Pagination, when the user scrolls near the end of the screen, the scrollController detects that and requests page 2, 3, 4, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the date header in a separator doesn't seem like the right approach to me. The separators are between each of the list elements, but not at the start or end of the list, so you always have one less separator than you do list element.

I would probably structure it so that you have a widget that represents a news day which contains the date header and the articles for that date, and then have a list view of these news day widgets.

Something along the lines of this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: TheNewsDemo(),
  ));
}

class TheNewsDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const TheNewsDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TheNewsDemoState createState() => _TheNewsDemoState();
}

class _TheNewsDemoState extends State<TheNewsDemo> {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> theNews = [
    {
      'day': 'March 3',
      'articles': [
        'News Article 1',
        'News Article 2',
      ],
    },
    {
      'day': 'March 4',
      'articles': [
        'News Article 3',
      ],
    },
    {
      'day': 'March 5',
      'articles': [
        'News Article 4',
        'News Article 5',
        'News Article 6',
      ],
    },
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: theNews.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          final element = theNews[index];
          return NewsDay(
            day: element['day'],
            articles: element['articles'],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NewsDay extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewsDay({
    Key? key,
    required this.day,
    required this.articles,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String day;
  final List<String> articles;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ExpansionTile(
      initiallyExpanded: true,
      title: Text(day),
      children: [
        for (final article in articles) NewsItem(article: article),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class NewsItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewsItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.article,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String article;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(title: Text(article));
  }
}
```